# Integrate Plugins to phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using Local Notification Plugin for andriod using PhoneGap Build,but its not working .

Here is my code

Config.xml:

```
            <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

and in Javascript:

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
        }
  </script>
```

it is not showing any notification. Please help me how to integrate 3rd party plugins for Andriod using phoneGap Build.

Comment: Did you include the js lib for you local notification plugin? Is there any errors?

Comment: yes included js file like    <script src="js/local-notification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: 3rd party plugins not working . please help me how to integrate .

Comment: If you are using PhoneGap Build, you definitely shouldn't include the js file in your project. And don't reference it anywhere in your JS/HTML. You only need to put the plugin in your config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Git Link**](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/e6548a0b9df92e4014fc5c2bd9eb840bb5bf418a)

Add Plugins in `Src` folder and give exact path in in `xml`.

Or else refer `plugins.xml` from above git code.